# Reverse value using '??' operator

Tags: c#, .net, operators

Is there an operator that makes reverse to '??' operator ?

```
int? value = 1;
var reverseValue = value ?? 5; // here I want to return 5 when the value is not null
```

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to create a custom operator like '!?' instead of writing long expression:

```
var reverseValue = value != null ? 5 : (int?)null;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no negation of ??, you have to go with

```
var reverseValue = value != null ? 5 : value;
```

Comment: Super minor, but I prefer returning the `(int?)null` or `default(int?)` rather than value because it makes the code more clearly show that null is being returned.

Comment: I agree to having code clearly show that null is beeing returned. But then I'd even go one step further and get rid of the 'var' too for a cleaner look: `int? reverseValue = value != null ? 5 : null;` ... but I guess thats for anyone to decide for themselves based on their taste :-)

Answer (score 1):

`var reverseValue = value != null ? 5 : (int?)null;`

Comment: I was just wondering if there is an operator (negation of '??')  instead of writing this long expression.

Comment: There's not.  I'm guessing the C# team (correctly) determined that this functionality would be confusing and make the language more bloated for a feature that doesn't solve a common usecase.

Answer (score 0):

he conditional operator should work for in this situation.

```
var reverseValue = value != null ? 5 : value;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

The part before the "?" is the condition. The part to the left of the ":" becomes the result if the condition is true. The part to the right of the ":" becomes the result if the condition is false.